# MySQL - Copying all stored procedure from one schema to another

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to copy all the stored procedures from one schema to another programmatically with an SQL script.

How can I do this in MySQL? I don't want to have to run a PHP script.

Thank you

EDIT: I am on MySQL 8. Table mysql.proc doesn't exist. Also, the schemas are on the same server.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) your comment is more as less *“You could Google this in 5 seconds.”*

Comment: You are right @RaymondNijland, sorry Vincent.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras I saw this post. I forgot to mention I am on MySQL 8. This post only gives a solution for MySQL 5.7, which has the mysql.proc table.

Comment: *"I need to copy all the stored procedures from one schema to another programmatically with an SQL script."* maybe this is easy possible with [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) and by using [QueryScript](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script.html) .. Now i think about it but not sure if this MySQL framework works on MySQL 8 i assume it would ..

Answer (score 3):

Dump the routines from one schema with mysqldump
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html

like

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt yourdb > yourdb.sql
```

and import into the new one

```
mysql -u root -p yournewdb < yourdb.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

reference

select * from `mysql`.`proc`

to obtain wat you want.
Good work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am on a MySQL 8.0 server. This table only available on 5.7.

Comment: SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines

Comment: What then? I have a list of stored procedures. How can I copy them to another schema programmatically from that? Including the parameters, etc.

Comment: @VincentL You can use `INSERT INTO information_schema.routines SELECT ... FROM information_schema.routines WHERE ...`

Comment: @Barmar I will get an access denied, as this is a view, not a table.

Comment: @BUcorp This will allow you to see the stored procedures, but how does it copy them?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just updated «db» column to new schema and after MySQL Workbench restart I saw the desired result.